# Paralleling a loop in C++ with OpenMP

Tags: c++, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

The solution that this parallelized returns doesn't match with the solution that it should be return, like the non-parallelized one.

```
    double angle=(PI/180)*atoi(extra);
    unsigned int xf;
    unsigned int yf;
    int j;    
    #pragma omp parallel for private (j,xf,yf)        
    for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
        for(j=0;j<height;j++){  
            xf=(unsigned int)ceil(((cos(angle)*(j-(((double)height)/2.0)))-(sin(angle)*(i-(((double)width)/2.0))))+(((double)height)/2.0));
            yf=(unsigned int)ceil(((sin(angle)*(j-(((double)height)/2.0)))+(cos(angle)*(i-(((double)width)/2.0))))+(((double)width)/2.0));
            if(xf<(unsigned int)height && xf>=0 && yf>=0 && yf<(unsigned int)width){
                  matrixRed2[yf][xf]=matrixRed[i][j];
                  matrixGreen2[yf][xf]=matrixGreen[i][j];
                  matrixBlue2[yf][xf]=matrixBlue[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your code entirely but it doesn't look as if the values of `yf` and `xf` will *necessarily* be different when the threads compute them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see it necessary for j, to be outside the loop since it just contain the temporary value before assigning to array (which have element independent). Moreover, two for loop can be collapsed. 
Edited: each xf, yf is not guarantee to be unique with  the formula from i, j. So keep the sequential one, Or you can try to check to keep the largest (i, j) if there race condition in (xf, yf). 
I'm not sure OpenMP can work on Visual Studio or not, since the supported version is very old (2.0 meanwhile the latest is 4.5).

Comment: @giorgioW what do you means "not working"? The result is incorrect? The time is not reduced?

Comment: @khôinguyễn I dont think your answer is correct. Imagine a situation where two different `(i,j)` pairs produce the same `(yf,xf)` pairs. Then in the non-parallel version, the `matrixColor2` matrix will hold the last time the `(yf,xf)` pair was produced. In the parallel version, you would have threads stomping over each other in this matrix, so the result is undetermined.  To OP: I don't believe this program can be adapted in parallel as-is. It is inherently a sequential operation.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Uhm maybe you're right. I didn't focus on the formula of xf, yf. It depend on the property of reversed transformation from xf,yf to i, j is one-to-one or not (the ceil function is not satisfied).